# Duplicate photos being returned whenever i query the 'photo tags' graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, photos

Im making a request to the graph api in the following format to get PHOTO TAGS for a user :

https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token={0}&format=json&since={1}&until={2}&limit={3}&fields=tags,id

Since i'm doing a query for anything up to 5 years period, i've tried splitting this request into

a) chunks of 2-12 months at a time
b) one big chunk

... But no matter what i do, im getting back duplicate photo's (i've checked this by grouping the results by id and getting batches of duplicate id's). If i ask for the WHOLE set of photo tags for a user, i get back 5 duplicates. If i chunk the request it appears to bring back even more.

Any reason why i might be getting duplicates? I've checked my logic and the date ranges all appear to be fine when making the requesr

Would there be a better way of doing this query - perhaps by doing the chunk via photo creation date rangs perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

When I HTTP Get `me/photos?fields=tags,id`, I get two objects: `.data` and `.paging`.  I would suggest, rather than using your own navigation, using the `paging.previous` and `paging.next` properties to navigate up/down the photos.  If you still get duplicates, then it would be a bug that you can report to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.